# Different color on private device than virtual device android studio

Tags: java, android, xml, colors

in layout view in android studio everything works fine. The problem is that button layout color and upper bar color which is #505050 is turning into light purple. Virtual device also shows this color as dark gray. Any solution to this problem? My phone is samsung galaxy s20.
Style of button "rounded_corners". Ive declared darkgray as #FF505050

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners android:radius="24dp" />
    <solid android:color="@color/darkgray" />
</shape>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of the app's theme. You can change it in app/res/values/themes/themes.xml file. Dont forget to change the both of the night and normal version of the themes file.